# Allow Anonymous Access to Document Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions

I am having issues allowing anonymous access to a document library.  At the site level I have allowed Anonymous Access to "`Entire Web site`" I have some links on my home page which all work fine, but one links to a document library and users are getting prompted for credentials.

When I edit the properties of the document library, and click "`permissions for this document library`", the click "`anonymous access`" it shows they have "`view items`" permissions.  This does not seem to be the case though, as mentioned unauthenticated users are prompted from their credentials.  Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:
After further investigation, I can get to the individual documents in the library fine, but I can not display a list of the library contents without authenticating.  Is there a way to do this?

Eg.
I can't get to "www.example.com/document_library/forms/allitems.aspx" without authenticating

Comment: I think this is related to your master page. Please try to access a file directly with an unauthenticated user. If this works there seems to be an other issue than the document library permissions. From what you've written, you've configured the doclib correctly.

Comment: So a little more info, I have a "main site" and several subsites.  On the main site I can access various document libraries unauthenticated.  On the particular subsite in question, this is the only document library and it asks me for credentials.

Comment: What would be the master page issue? Sorry I'm fairly new to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed each steps rightly
1)Enabling the anonymous access to the Web application from Central Admin

[image]

2)Enabling the Anonymous permissions in Web application settings. Go to Site Permission screen
[image]
[image]

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569965/GrantingplusAnonymousplusAccessplustoplusSharepoin

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I have allowed "Entire Web site" access to my users.

Answer (score 0):

Since displaying an entire document library to unauthenticated users doesn't seem to be possible, as a workaround I created a page where I can add documents to be displayed to users as required.